# Angular js $scope error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I trying to get on my feet with angular.js using the seed app.

When the browser executes my controller i get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'players' of undefined
at new bankC (http://localhost:8888/monopoly/js/controllers.js:18:20)
at invoke (http://localhost:8888/monopoly/lib/angular/angular.js:2795:28)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8888/monopoly/lib/angular/angular.js:2805:23)
at http://localhost:8888/monopoly/lib/angular/angular.js:4620:24
at update (http://localhost:8888/monopoly/lib/angular/angular.js:13692:26)
at http://localhost:8888/monopoly/lib/angular/angular.js:8002:24
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (http://localhost:8888/monopoly/lib/angular/angular.js:110:11)
at Object.Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:8888/monopoly/lib/angular/angular.js:8000:11)
at http://localhost:8888/monopoly/lib/angular/angular.js:7185:26
```

this is the controller code which is the controller.js file

```
function bankC($scope) {
  $scope.players = [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "Playe1",
        balance: 1500
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Player2",
        balance: 1500
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Player 3",
        balance: 1500
      }
  ];
}
bankC.$inject = [];
```

Thanks

EDIT:

its registered with angular js to be used when on a certain "page"

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives']).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: MyCtrl1});
    $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: MyCtrl2});
    $routeProvider.when('/bank', {templateUrl: 'partials/bank.html', controller: bankC});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/bank'});
}]);
```

EDIT2:

Removing "bankC.$inject = [];" from the controller file solved the problem, so why does the angular.js seed app include it?

Comment: are you sure that you're calling the function with a defined parameter, not undefined?

Comment: how would i define the parameter in angularjs? This may be where im going wrong....

Comment: how is the `bankC` function called?

Comment: see edit, i've added where its registered

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting that error because of the last line

```
bankC.$inject = [];
```

This tells the angular injector to inject nothing into the controller while the controller is looking for $scope.

If you change this to

```
bankC.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

it should work fine.

That last line exists because angular uses Dependancy Injection. Angular looks for variables with name $scope when you request for it in a controller. But if the code is minified then the obfuscation will change the name of $scope to something else. In order to maintain sanity when this happens that last line is introduced. When ever you declare a new controller the best practice would be to include that last line with all the variables you want angulars DI to inject into that controller.

Note : If you are interested in getting more things injected into that controller ( or similiar controllers ) then you will have to update bankC.$inject as well.

Comment: Should angularjs automatically do this as i have registered that controller with that url page?

Comment: Angular automatically calls / instantiates the corresponding controller. 
It would be good if you provide your html or your app.js where you would have referenced bankC.

Comment: im using partials so the controller isnt registered in any HTML, it is registered in the app.js which i've added to my original question.

Comment: any idea why this fixed it? It seems odd that the seed app came with this code that once removed fixed my problem.

Comment: @Cooltrooper That last line exists because angular uses Dependancy Injection. Angular looks for variables with name $scope when you request for it in a controller. But if the code is minified then the obfuscation will change the name of $scope to something else. In order to maintain sanity when this happens that last line is introduced. When ever you declare a new controller the best practice would be to include that last line with all the variables you want angulars DI to inject into that controller.

Comment: I have almost the same problem with obfuscation. Even though I inject my service into controller obfuscated code wont work. I create service like this:
angular.module("myModule", []).factory "myService", ->

And than inject it into controller like this:
@MyCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "myService"]

Obfuscation will leave "myService" but it will rename MyCtrl definition and parameter names. Do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: You may be able to tell your obfusicator to ignore some parameters, though im of the school that code doesn't need obfuscation anyway. The obfuscation seems to be treating the two variables as different items rather than the same one, giving them two different variable names, thus the interpreter not being able to see the correct variable, as the Obfuscation has changed the variable you are after to something else.